# Using a Setter with Multidimensional Arrays

Tags: php, mongodb, object, getter-setter

I'm trying to create a __set for an object in PHP that works with multidimensional arrays. Is this even possible?

I would like to be able to something like the following: `$post->comments[0]['uid']=3;`. However, comments is actually going to be a key in a private cache variable `$_cache['comments']=array()`. It'd be nice if the __set function could somehow get both the base key (comments) and the index (0) as well as the key/value it is setting (uid/3). However, that's not possible.

I've thought about making `$_cache['comments']` and array of ArrayObjects but that wouldn't let me define a custom _*get/*_set overload. Instead, I think that I might end up having to create a new Comments object and then fill the array with those. However, I really wouldn't like to do this and it'd be sweet if somehow PHP could handle nested arrays in __set overloads.

I'm using Mongo and would like if I could just have one single object for each document. However, arrays objects in Mongo are creating a bit of a problem for me. I would like to just handle them as an array in PHP but that doesn't seem possible. The setter needs to take `$post->comments[0]['uid']=3` and update both the cache as well as setting `$this->data['comments'][0]['uid']=3`.

I know that if comments was an array of objects I could do this:

```
$post->comments[0]->uid=3; 
///Sets $_cache['comments'][0]->uid=3;
```

And it would work because the getter for comments would return the array of objects and allow it to access the uid property. I could then have a getter/setter within the comments object that would somehow edit the `$post->data` through a pseudo "friend" function/hack. However, I don't see an easy way of accomplishing this with arrays....

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's more complex than you actually imagine. You can accomplish what you want with a heap of workarounds, but it's seldomly worth the effort.

If `->comments` itself is resolved by a getter method, than assigning something to the `[0]` subarray won't actually end up in the private property. And `->comments[0]=` will not even invoke your setter method. Instead this is a read access.

To make this work at all you would have to make your __get method return an reference of `& $this->_cache['comments']`.

If you want to intercept set accesses in that `comments` array you would indeed need [`ArrayObject`](http://php.net/ArrayObject). The difference is that this requires to override `offsetGet` and `offsetSet` instead of `__get` and `__set`. But again, since you are accessing a further subarray, the __get method will actually be used and you need to return another reference, or yet again a level of ArrayObject workaround goo.

Comment: I could swear something like `foreach($post->comments as $x){ $x->uid=4}` works  where post::__get returns an array of comment objects. Are you sure that `$post->comments[0]->uid=4` wouldn't work?

Comment: If it contains an subobject `[0]->uid` instead of array `[0]['uid']`, then it will work because it references the same object. But array accesses work by copy per default.

Comment: That said, I'm going to mess around with references and see if I can get it working with what I need.

Comment: @Mario Wait, so there really isn't any way to get this to work "automatically" without having objects for each element in the array. I'm trying to map a series of rather complex Mongo documents that change quite often I'm currently setting up the schema as an array in each object and although I'm using "subobjects" for the more complex models, I'd like to just be able to use a simple nested array and have everything work without having to create a new object every single time. Is there any way you can think of to get this to work?

Comment: I tried to come up with something similar. You can of course design a `MagicArrayObject` class that you attach to the __get/offsetGet methods. It will have to auto-convert any accessed subarrays, and if possible keep a reference to the original array. -- But just with simple arrays it doesn't seem doable to me. You should rather give up on being able to observe set accesses there. PHP makes that too difficult.

Comment: Yeah, every time I run into this type of problem I end up eventually just figuring out a work around rather than making it happen automatically. I think having an extended ArrayObject class aka MagicArrayObject that uses some sort of "friend" function or just use a reference and send data modifications back to the base object is going to be the best way for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I jumped through some of these hoops when building my own PHP wrapper class.

https://github.com/gatesvp/MongoModel

It's still in the the works, but it does handle some basic "map this object to DB".

Answer (score 1):

There's virtually nothing worthwhile written in PHP chat rooms or the php documentation that's going to be useful to you, Adam.  Most of the suggestions tend along the lines of implementing `interface ArrayAccess` or extending `class ArrayObject`, both in the SPL.  In fact, there is a surprisingly straightforward solution to your problem: `$post->comments[0]['uid']=3` using overloaded setter `__set()`.

Define `private $comments = array();` in class `post`.  For convenience, use a text key for the first subscript of `$comments`: here, integer 0 becomes, say, "zero".  You then invoke the setter as follows:

```
$post->zero = ['uid', 3];
```

This invokes the magic setter because there is no publicly declared property `$zero` in class `post`: "The overloading methods are invoked when interacting with properties or methods that have not been declared or are not visible in the current scope." (PHP 5 man page on [Overloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members).)

The setter can also be `setComments()`, a convenience because you won't have to discriminate among incoming properties to identify those intended for array `comments`, but the calling syntax becomes less natural.

Your overloaded, auto-magical function `__set` receives two arguments: a property and a value:

```
public function __set($property, $value) {
```

very reminiscent of Crockford's JSON protocol.  It is helpful to think of it in those terms.

Since property "zero" that you sent in does not exist in class`post`, it needs to be trapped, and my preferred method, since the first subscript in property `comments` will likely have several values, is to define a private array of supported subscript values in `post`:

```
private $indices = [
     "zero"  => 0,
     "one"   => 1,
     "two"   => 2,
     "three" => 3 
];
```

When the index for `comments` arrives in `__set()` as `$property`, it is verified to exist in `$indices`.  Now you simply iterate through the array supplied in `$value`, extract 
`uid` and its corresponding value, then assign to `$comments` as follows:

```
public function __set($property, $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($property, $this->indices) && is_array($value))
        foreach ($value as $uid => $uid_value)  
            $this->comments[$this->indices[property]][$uid] = $uid_value;
    else
        ...
}
```

with `$this->indices[property]` being used to extract the integer value 0 to be used to
index the first dimension of `comments`, and `$uid_value` extracted with value int 3 to be assigned.

The approach outlined here is not a gimmick, workaround or clever trick.  It's a straightforward design technique intended to work with one of SPL's facilities and can, in principle, be extended to arrays of arbitrary dimension.  I have the design implemented in a production system so, if you're still having difficulty, post here and I'll help you to debug your application.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the closest you can do for overloading some properties is to use the magic method __set() defined here: http://us.php.net/__set

I am not sure you can handle the [0] before it gets taken by the PHP compiler...

So your other solution would be to transform comments into a method

```
public function comments($id) {
   return $this->obj[$id]; // Obj
}
```

And the object you return has the __set property

```
class Obj {
   private $id;
   public function __set($key, $value) {
       if($key === 'uid') {
           $_cache = $GLOBALS['_cache'];
           $_cache['comments'][$this->id]->uid = $value;
       }
   }
}
```

There is a lot of code missing here, but you can figure out how to do it with this __set method()

Comment: I updated my original post to perhaps explain what I'm trying to do a bit better. I'm already using __set overloading. It works with one dimensional arrays of objects ($this->comments[0]->uid) but it does not work for multidimensional arrays.

Comment: Well, the thing is you want to have $comments[0] to RETURN a value. So in that case, if you can do it with \__get(), that's perfect. Then once you returned an Obj value (like my class exemple) you can work with the \__set() magic reference this time to make the uid = 3 work.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function instead of trying to hack it on top of something that isn't even meant for that.

```
public function setCommentUid($commentId, $uid) {
    $this->_cache['comments'][$commentId]->uid = $uid;
}

//then...
$post->setCommentUid(0, 3);
```

This makes it much simpler to use the class and it's much easier to see what it does.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm looking for a solution for a base class that I can extend for each implementation. I'm using Mongo and would like to just be able to throw my document model at it and let everything happen "automagically". I'm sure there's some solution out there....

Comment: Depending on what sort of functionality you need to happen automatically, using `__call` might work. You could use it to allow calls to functions which don't exist, and dynamically handle it so that the values go into the arrays you want. I do have a feeling that what you're doing might not be the best approach, but it's hard to judge with the information available and it's probably out of scope for this question anyway :)

Comment: In the base class, why not `set($cachevar, $id, $basevar, $baseval)` and call `$this->_cache[$cachevar][$id]->$basevar = $baseval`?